# Is it most efficient to have one variable initialization in outer function or multiple in inner function?

Tags: c++

This:

```
int something(num){
    int arr[] = {1,3,5,7};
    //check if num is in arr... If yes, return num, otherwise return 0.
}

int main(){
    something(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Vs.

```
int something(num, &parr){
    //check if num is in parr... If yes, return num, otherwise return 0.
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 3, 5, 7};
    something(5, arr);

    return 0;
}
```

And why? I would choose to believe that number two is most efficient, because that there will only happen one initialization for the array, whereas in code number 1, there happen an initialization of the array each time we would call `something()`; and don't initializations take time to perform?

Comment: measuring > speculations

Comment: also you can take a look at the output of the compiler to see what is the difference: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Outside may be faster, baring sneaky compiler switcheroos, because `arr` will be recreated every time in the function. A better option is to leave `arr` in the function, but declare it `static` so it is only created once.

Comment: Are you serious: `check if num is in arr... If yes, return num, otherwise return 0.`?

Comment: Pretty sure they're serious. I'm the only person who gets to make jokes around here.

Comment: btw first of all you should take care that your code expresses your intent. If the function uses always the same array, then passing it to the function each time you call it is obfuscating your original intent (array is always the same)

Comment: It is more efficient to write readable code, you spent much more time debugging than executing.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @tobi303 but in my example code, wouldn't it be most optimal to go with code number 2? I mean let's say that we run something() 100 times, then we could save 99 initializations and destructions?

Comment: @sdsad - How do you know if passing an extra parameter 100 times is faster than initializing the array. And if it is, on a PC we are still talking nanoseconds here. I would go with `const int arr[]` and trust the compiler to handle that.

Comment: @BoPersson would you have `const int arr[] inside `something()`, why not in `main`? Is that only for readability reasons?

Comment: @sdsadasdasd the correct way would be option 3: declare the array `static` inside the function: only one initalization even if you call it 1 million times (100 times is not something you should ever worry about). And it should be `const` too

Comment: @tobi303 is the reason why you would declare the array inside the function to improve readability? Also, why also declare it const if you already have declared it static? There will be one initialization in both cases?

Comment: `const` and `static` are orthogonal concepts. If it is `static` it could still change between function call, but as you dont want it to change you should declare it `const`. Yes it is for readability. If you want an orange then you write "orange" and not "apple" and explain everybody reading the code that it looks like "apple" but you are supposed to pronounce it as "orange" (I love exaggerated analogies ;)

Comment: @tobi303 ahh thanks! But regarding `const`, would you only use it for readability in this case or also for expectations of some optimization done by the compiler? Or is that not what to think about?

Comment: @sdsadasdasd afaik in most cases the compiler is clever enough to realize that a variable does not change its value even if you dont declare it as `const`. Yes, again this is for readability. It is to remind you that it is not supposed to change and to enable the compiler to throw an error at you in case you try to modify it accidentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In speed testing Option A versus option B the answer is, "Hard to say." You'd have to profile and find out. A smart compiler may note that `arr` never changes and is never modified and optimize accordingly.

But...

`arr` should stay as close as possible to where it is used to enhance readability, so this is a point for option A. Plus, declaring `arr` as a `static` variable eliminates the re-initialization problem entirely.

```
int something(int num){
    const static int arr[] = {1,3,5,7}; // const so it is harder to accidentally change
    //check if num is in arr... If yes, return num, otherwise return 0.
}
```

As a `static`, `arr` is initialized exactly once and hangs around until the program ends (which in a resource constrained environment may be a problem of its own).

Comment: Yea okay, thanks. But are you implying that multiple constructions of objects are slower than only one? Also, as I just asked tobi, wouldn't it be most optimal to go with code number 2 theoretically? I mean let's say that we run something() 100 times, then we could save 99 initializations and destructions? If the compiler is not smart. Like if we should not think about readability :-)

Comment: @sdsadasdasd Multiple initializations, if they occur, will be slower than one. But the compiler am smart. It may notice that multiple initializations are not required and turn option 1 into something like the `static` approach. The only way to be absolutely certain that Option 1 is slower than option 2 is to make a release build, do a couple billion calls to `something` and try out both options.

Comment: That said you're better of writing your program the easiest, simplest possible way, and profiling it to pinpoint exactly what is too slow. Nothing may be too slow. Don't make something fast for the sake of making it fast. Make it fast because it needs to be fast. You don't get paid big bucks to obsess over insignificant details when there are significant details to obsess over.